# Blackberry: Creating a ListView or TableView like screen in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry

I'm not sure where to begin, but I've been trying to find a similar class that allows me to create a scrollable list where I can add images and text.

I found a tutorial using PictureScrollField, but I dont think that is what I need. Is FlowFieldManager the closest thing?

Edit:

I see that there is a tableView class in Blackberry. However, it says BlackBerry API 6.0.0, so does that mean it won't work with bb's 5.0?

Comment: That is correct.  Older versions do have a `TreeField` class, though.

Comment: Let me know are you getting or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For BlackBerry, typically you use a [ListField](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.1.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/ListField.html) to build a scrollable list.  It does have some constraints though:  Each item needs to have the same height, and you have to do all the drawing yourself, instead of using the more typical field + manager layout used for BlackBerry screens.  The upside of those constraints is that the drawing performance is quite good.

Answer (score 0):

In following link some specified Layouts are available OS5.0 also
like table view,grid view and spreadsheet layouts
just copy paste that class into your project then you can use this

- [using TableModel-TableView-TableController](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Using-TableModel-TableView-TableController-and-DataTemplate-to/ta-p/617305)
- [GridTable-SpreadSheet-layout-manager](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Grid-table-spreadsheet-layout-manager/td-p/250508)

if it is not useful to you just ignore this

Answer (score 0):

I used `FieldManager` classes to do this.  As an example you can use:

`net.rim.device.api.ui.container.VerticalFieldManager.`

And for images I have used following kind of code.

```
InputStream inputStream = connection.openInputStream();

            byte[] data = IOUtilities.streamToBytes(inputStream);


            EncodedImage img = EncodedImage.createEncodedImage(data, 0,  data.length);
            img.setScale(3);

            imgOK.setImage(img);
```

Comment: I used HttpConnection for get images.